# how scroll right popup window

Tags: javascript

I`m using this function to open popup windows in my site.
I want to scroll right (It is RTL) the window content, but it  isnt working:

```
popupWins[name].scrollRight += 1000;
```

Any ideas?

```
popupWins = new Array();

function windowOpener(url, name, args) {
/*******************************
the popupWins array stores an object reference for
each separate window that is called, based upon
the name attribute that is supplied as an argument
*******************************/
if ( typeof( popupWins[name] ) != "object" ){
popupWins[name] = window.open(url,name,args);
} else {
if (!popupWins[name].closed){
popupWins[name].location.href = url;
} else {
popupWins[name] = window.open(url, name,args);
}
}

popupWins[name].scrollRight += 1000;
popupWins[name].focus();


}
```

Comment: have you tried popupWins[name].scrollLeft += 1000?

Comment: Does adding setTimeout helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
popupWins[name].document.body.scrollLeft += 1000;
```

Comment: it works only when I opening the window more times. the first time it isnt working/

Comment: when I call function the first time it isn't working. when I calling more times (that window is already open) it works.

Comment: Probably you need to add a small delay using setTimeout function, as for the first time it might be taking some time to load the page...

Comment: Other solution is write a code in the onload event of the window html